# Welcome message JSP JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have create a simple web application in which someone can register e login.
Now where someone logs I want that appear "Welcome  "
Now this is the code of:

> login.java

I add a logged-in to check if someone is logged in the site, but I don't think that it's right.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package hotel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Login extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {

            String s1 = request.getParameter("t1");
            String s2 = request.getParameter("t2");
            out.print("Welcome "+ s1);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            out.println("driver loaded");
            Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation","root" ,"123456789");
            out.println("Connect");
            Statement  st =  con.createStatement();
            out.println("conncetion successfull");

                ResultSet rs =   st.executeQuery("select email,uid, pass from register where email = '"+s1+"' and pass = '"+s2+"'");
                rs.next();    
                String cid = rs.getString("uid");
                out.println("recod is inserted" +cid);




          HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
          session.setAttribute("sessname",cid);
         // out.println("<a href=\"LoginSucess.jsp\">Check Output Page Here </a>");
          session.setAttribute("logged-in","true");


          String redirectedPage = "/parentPage";
          response.sendRedirect("loginsuccess.jsp");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Driver not found" +e);
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

I want put this message in a nav menu, do you know how can I do?
For example I have created this:

```
<% String name="";
    if(session.getAttribute("Logged-in") != null) {
    name = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
} else {
    // response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}

%>
<div id="container">
<div id="nav">       
        <a href="home.jsp">Home</a>
        <a href="hotel.jsp">Hotel</a>
        <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
        <a href="registration.jsp">Registrazione</a>
        Welcome <%= name %>
</div>
```

But I receive only: "Welcome".
Thanks you

Comment: There is no such variable (name ) in session you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your code is not working because some error are there at in your code. here this is your code.

<% String name="";
    if(session.getAttribute("Logged-in") != null)
    {
       name = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
    }
    else 
    {
      // response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }

%>

now in this your code "name" parameter not set in your controller side. so if you simply write this code in your controller side then your problem is solved.

 session.setAttribute("name",cid);

put this code in your controller side and again run your project.
```

Comment: " my controller side" is the login.java? Because I put this string there and I receive only Welcome

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JnxCSHdU
I have created this document with all the interested file!

Answer (score 0):

You are no where storing the information of the login credentials. Try to store it into controller or fetch the values into servlet and use it.

Or ...

You initialized the session as "logged-in" and used it as "Logged-in". Try to change it as its case sensitive.
 --> session.setAttribute("logged-in","true");

--> if(session.getAttribute("Logged-in") != null) {

Comment: So ... Try to verify where actually your values are going. As per given you code I wasn't able to know the value anywhere coming to servlet.

Try to write this lines and use them again...:
Boolean flag = request.getParameter(session.getAttribute());
Now check condition with flag's value.
Also you can check on console that is flag actually changing or not. So that you will come to know you changes are affecting or not.
For any further queries, you can reach me directly on : maniarchirag57@gmail.com